# How to pass a var from one page to another in blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

How to pass a data (ex userid ) from one page to another page in blackberry 10 qml ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either create property on target page or create a java script function to do so. If you  want to validate or perform any other operation before assigning you should use java script function.

```
Page {
    //targetPage

    property string userid //you can also use alias here

    function initialize(id) {
        userid = id
        //you can also set property of controls here
    }
}
```

Call it on your page like this

```
targetPageid.userid = "user id"
```

OR

```
targetPageid.initialize("user id")
```

Comment: I'm trying to access a function on home page from my main page which has a navigation pane and on poptransition I need to call a method on homepage and I tried as per your method but didnt work. It shows targetPageid not found. I have declared targetPageid as homepage id. Do I have to include anything else to access it on my main page?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in your `cpp`

```
qml->setContextProperty("MyApp",this);
```

And then call the method using this object. i called a method in a button in my `main.qml`

```
Button{
        id : button
        text : "Connect"
        onClicked: 
            {   
                MyApp.PostData("46565652","sotho")
            }
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
    }
```